# Getting distinct value from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I have below data records in my `MongoDB` collection;

```
{
    "_id": { "8uk4f9653fc4gg04dd7ab3d3"},
    "title": "my title",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1ethd485",
    "author": "john",
    "created": { "2020-05-20T08:25:47.438Z"},
    "vote": 1619
},
{
    "_id": { "6fd4fgh53fc4gg04dd7gt56d"},
    "title": "my title",
    "url": "https://myurl/entry/1ethd485",
    "author": "john",
    "created": { "2020-05-19T04:12:47.457Z"},
    "vote": 1230
}
```

As you can see **title**, **url** and **author** could be same but **_id**, **created** and **vote** is **always unique**.

This is my `Route` in `app.js`;

```
// Home Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  Entry.find({}).sort({ "vote" : -1 }).limit(500).exec(function(err, entries){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render('index', {
        entries: entries
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This route is displaying 500 records descending order of vote value. This is displaying both records above that have vote values 1619 and 1230. However what i want to achieve is to display only the biggest vote value for same title, url and author. In this example it should display only the record with vote value 1619. What is the best way to do it? What is the correct way of using [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct) in here?

And just for your reference this is my pug layout;

```
extends layout
    block content
      h1 #{title}
      ul.list-group
        each entry, i in entries
          li.list-group-item
            a(href=entry.url)= entry.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    model.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$author", author: { $first: "$author" }, vote: { $max: "$vote" }, url: { $first: "$url" }, title: { $first: "$title" } } },{ $sort:{ vote:-1} },{ $limit: 500 }]).exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        res.send(result)
    })
})`

Comment: Hmm this seems bringing results but  it does not sort by vote descending.

Comment: you can sort it in decesending order for vote as well . `{
    $sort:{ vote:-1}
  }` apply this object inside your aggregate function.

Comment: could you please add it into the answer so that i can accept it as answer.

Comment: i have eddited the answer , you can try. now

Comment: Sorry but this is not sorting votes by descending order. It's sorting in random.

Comment: i have made the changes to the answers this will definetly work .

Comment: Ok it is sorting now : ) one last thing and thanks a lot for your patience. can you pls apply limit 500 criteria as well?

Comment: i have added the limit as well , you can try it out

Answer (score 1):

```
if you have to find out distinct along with maximum value the you can use the following command:

`Entry.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$author",votevalue:{$max:"$vote"}}}]);`
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more. How this fit with my "Entry.find({}).sort({ "vote" : -1 }).limit(500)" criteria. I still want to use it as well.

Comment: you can use this `Entry.distinct("author").exec((err,results))` the problem with this approch is it will return you object with min value as well . But in the above what happens  is it will select the same check pick a distinct one with max vote number . I think you want to retreive the max vote along with unique author object .

Comment: Actually i want max vote along with unique author, title and url.

Comment: this approch will retrieve the entire object with author, title and url

Comment: It's not working for me. Could you please apply it to the full code?

Comment: i have made the changes for you and posted the code down below try it in your application you will get the results